# Configuring SimpleHTTPServer to assume '.html' for suffixless URLs

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

How can I configure the Python module "SimpleHTTPServer" such that e.g. `foo.html` is opened when e.g. `http://localhost:8000/foo` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Juan Fco. Roco's answer mostly does what I needed, but I ended up using a solution inspired by [Clokep's solution for his own blog](https://github.com/clokep/clokep.github.io/tree/source).

The most relevant part is the content of [my fake_server.py](https://github.com/tohuw/tohuwnet/blob/780f5db06cfec1e4bf83bd5e60361e80f39f7fe0/fake_server.py), but the originating call is in [my fabfile.py](https://github.com/tohuw/tohuwnet/blob/780f5db06cfec1e4bf83bd5e60361e80f39f7fe0/fabfile.py#L30-L43)

### fake_server.py

```py
import os
import SimpleHTTPServer

class SuffixHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    """
    Overrides the default request handler to assume a suffixless resource is
    actually an html page of the same name. Thus, http://localhost:8000/foo
    would find foo.html.

    Inspired by:
    https://github.com/clokep/clokep.github.io/blob/source/fake_server.py
    """
    def do_GET(self):
        path = self.translate_path(self.path)

        # If the path doesn't exist, assume it's a resource suffixed '.html'.
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            self.path = self.path + '.html'

        # Call the superclass methods to actually serve the page.
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

SimpleHTTPServer.test(SuffixHandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can configure it to do that... the fastest way is monkeypatching:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import os

SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.translate_path = lambda self, filename: os.getcwd() + filename + ".html"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleHTTPServer.test()
```

You probably will break directory listing, so you should check if the path is a directory before adding .html to it.

You can check here more elaborated examples: [SimpleHTTPServer add default.htm default.html to index files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042076/simplehttpserver-add-default-htm-default-html-to-index-files)

Hope this helps